# CREATE_FAILED while creating the CloudFormation Stack from Hyperledger template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, hyperledger-fabric

I am using this template to create the stack:

https://aws-blockchain-templates-us-east-1.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/hyperledger/fabric/templates/simplenetwork/latest/hyperledger.template.yaml

While following this blog-post from AWS, I am getting an error.

Blog - Post Link :

https://aws.amazon.com/blockchain/templates/getting-started/

Region : us-east-1

Error Message :

The following resource(s) failed to create: [FabricEC2CommonStack]. . Rollback requested by user.
CREATE_FAILED   AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  FabricEC2CommonStack    Embedded stack arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:>:stack/FabricStack-FabricEC2CommonStack-NNFUD6RJCZB1/<> was not successfully created: The following resource(s) failed to create: [EC2InstanceForDev].

I have met all the prerequisites.

What could be the reason for this error and how to rectify it?

After this, I get ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS and ROLLBACK_COMPLETE.

Comment: You should be able to look in the CloudFormation console and see the error output in the events section

Comment: I checked the events...from there only I posted the error message.

Answer (score 0):

The Official AWS Blockchain Cloud Formation Template for Hyperledger Fabric is a nested template (our base template calls another template which does all the setup on an EC2 instance which itself creates).

But the problem is it does everything on the EC2-Instance except installing docker-compose & it throws an error that docker-compose command not found at the end which causes the CloudFormation template to break(EC2InstanceForDev) and do a rollback. So instead of using CloudFormation Template, we can run the same script manually on the EC2-instance with a small change. The change is to install docker-compose beforehand. Rest setup remains the same i.e -- **1. Create a VPC, 2. Create Public Subnets, 3. Create EIP if you want to attach it later, 4. Create Key-Pair for SSH, 5. Create IAM Role & Policy, 6. Create Security Group with Inbound 8080(TCP) & 22(SSH), 7. launch an EC2 Instance with the created resources in step (1to6).**

**AMI which is preferred is -**

1. ami-1853ac65 for us-east-1
2. ami-25615740 for us-east-2
3. ami-dff017b8 for us-west-2

**Docker Image Repository -**

1. 354658284331 for us-east-1
2. 763976151875 for us-east-2
3. 712425161857 for us-west-2

**SCRIPT TO RUN ON EC2** (Give chmod 777 and chmod +x for the script) -

```
#!/bin/bash -x
sudo curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.22.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m) -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose
docker-compose --version
res=$?
echo $res
mkdir /tmp/fabric-install/
cd /tmp/fabric-install/
wget https://aws-blockchain-templates-us-east-1.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/hyperledger/fabric/templates/simplenetwork/latest/HyperLedger-BasicNetwork.tgz -O /home/ec2-user/HyperLedger-BasicNetwork.tgz
cd /home/ec2-user
tar xzvf HyperLedger-BasicNetwork.tgz
rm /home/ec2-user/HyperLedger-BasicNetwork.tgz
chown -R ec2-user:ec2-user HyperLedger-BasicNetwork
chmod +x /home/ec2-user/HyperLedger-BasicNetwork/artifacts/first-run-standalone.sh
/home/ec2-user/HyperLedger-BasicNetwork/artifacts/first-run-standalone.sh us-east-1 example.com org1 org2 org3 mychannel 354658284331.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ 354658284331
res=$?
echo $res
```

IAM policy which I attached to the role -

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:GetRepositoryPolicy",
                "ecr:DescribeRepositories",
                "ecr:ListImages",
                "ecr:DescribeImages",
                "ecr:BatchGetImage"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
]
}
```

**NOTE** -
Please replace the appropriate AWS ECR account number for your region and appropriate AWS region in the above script and script has (example.com org1 org2 org3 mychannel), Please change this too as per requirement. Its the same RootDomain, Org1SubDomain, Org2SubDomain, Org3SubDomain, ChannelName as we enter in the CF template).

This whole process is tested in the us-east-1 region. The script can be straight deployed in the us-east-1 region. To access the Hyperledger web monitor interface (`http://EC2-DNS OR EIP:8080`)

Answer (score -1):

You should be Checking your IAM Role and It fixed my issue.

Comment: Thanks Vallu.My user has AdministratorAccess Policy with everything allowed.

Comment: Also the role I am using is "EC2ToECRandS3" has following JSON:            
"Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:GetRepositoryPolicy",
                "ecr:DescribeRepositories",
                "ecr:ListImages",
                "ecr:DescribeImages",
                "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"

Comment: Did this get resolved Deep ? I am getting the same error - not sure why ?